# Batch setting file permissions from gsheet script to drive (I can't set folder permissions)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I'm trying to change the permissions of 1000s of files. I can't set the folder permissions because I'm a "contributor" and not a manager, or a content manager. (which would've been much easier)

I have written this code to iterate through each file one by one and set it's permission.

```
function grantaccesstoprivateids(){
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("PictureIDs");
//var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();

// Skip the header row
for (var i = 2; i <= lastRow; i++) {
  Logger.log(sheet.getRange(i, 6));
  if (sheet.getRange(i, 6).getValue() == "PRIVATE") {
    var fileID = sheet.getRange(i, 4).getValue();

    var file = DriveApp.getFileById(fileID);
    try {
      file.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.ANYONE_WITH_LINK,DriveApp.Permission.VIEW);
      sheet.getRange(i, 6).setValue("Code ran to share with all");
    }
    catch (err) {
      sheet.getRange(i, 6).setValue(err);
    }
  }
}
}
```

The issue is this is slow... (about 1 per second) I would love to make an array of each ID and then tell google, these 1000s of IDS? Please share them all to ANYONE_WITH_LINK.

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

```
function grantaccesstoprivateids(){
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh=ss.getSheetByName('PicturIDs');
  const sr=2;
  const c4=sh.getRange(sr,4,sh.getLastRow()-sr+1).getValues();
  const c6=sh.getRange(sr,6,sh.getLastRow()-sr+1).getValues();
  c6.forEach((c,i)=>{
    if(c[0]=='PRIVATE') {
      let file=DriveApp.getFileById(c4[i+sr][0]);
      try {
        file.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.ANYONE_WITH_LINK,DriveApp.Permission.VIEW);
        c[0]="Code ran to share with all";
      }
      catch(e) {
        c[0]=e;
      }
    }
  });
  sh.getRange(sr,6,c6.length,1).setValues(c6);
}
```

It might be a little faster.  If not then drive Drive API

[Best Practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices)

Comment: Cool, I've sat through the 5000 files now 1 by 1 by now. Your method looks like it will be the same speed, but at least everything is in 'memory' and if the spreadsheet changes mid execution no issues would occur.  My only issue with your method is that if I time out, then I would have no idea where the time out occurred, but not interacting with the front end until I've finished should probably make it quite a bit faster.

Comment: With 5000 files to deal with I suspect that no matter which course you take you will ultimately have to find a method that allows you to perform the process as a restartable batch.  Perhaps keeping track of which i your on will allow to keep track of a recoverable index and use that to begin the process again from where you left off.

Answer (score 0):

Making a batch request to the Drive API will surely be faster. You are limited to 100 calls per batch though. But you can make multiple batch requests. See [Drive API batch](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/batch#overview)